# Review link doesn't appear for <125 rep users, though there's a site self-evaluation going on

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, review

I'm on this site a <125 rep user, so it's normal that I don't see a review link in the <strike>top bar</strike> sub-top bar. However, there's a site self-evaluation going on and I do have the privilege to participate in that.

Shouldn't the review link appear for everyone that does have the privilege to participate in an active review queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue here is that you guys aren't supposed to be running a self-evaluation at all. :) They have been disabled on all other graduated sites and should be disabled here by the time I'm writing this as well.

On a beta site, this is also normally not an issue since the evaluation is linked from the community bulletin and accompanied by a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta post that draws enough attention to the queue... but I'll double-check with Emmett how the review link shows up in the top bar when he gets back from vacation next week.

Comment: So could you also give Emmett's address so that I can steal everything? Thanks for the response - the self-evaluation now totally disappeared, although I can see the other review queues. I guess that's by-design as well? :)

Comment: @CamilStaps Yes - it's been disabled as it should've been a long time ago.

Comment: THANK YOU! That site evaluation has been driving me absolutely crazy! There's never been anything for me to review...

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this review?

[image]

If this is what you're referring to, this is not a site review, but it a Privilege that you get once you hit 2000 points.  For more information see 
[Edit questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit)

Comment: This is indeed what I'm referring to. On other sites where I have privilege to do some or all reviews, I got the review link. This is not a 10000 rep privilege (although the "5" icon probably is, never seen that before), as far as I know. You could test it on [SU] ;)

Comment: @CamilStaps Yes, the five is a 10k privilege. It either lists the number of pending flags or current pending edits.